# Daylight savings time for real time application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am building an application on windows forms C# that will run in real time 24 hours a day 365 days a year. This application tracks the time that components are out of storage.

I am running into a problem with daylight savings time as when it hits, it will alter how long the components are out, which i need to deal with.

Im wondering if there is a built in function in .NET that handles this or if others have had this issue and know a solution?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is the reason that UTC was established. (https://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html)  In general it is best to store and compare dates in UTC, and if necessary display in the local time zone.

Comment: For C# and date handling, the smart money is on using [nodatime](https://nodatime.org/).

Comment: @BerinLoritsch: UTC still has leap seconds, though. If you need a monotonous, linear timescale without "jumps", TAI may be a better choice.

Comment: So i use UTC and perodically check it, readjusting it when neccecary?

Comment: Nevermind just found UTC never changes. Thanks for the help! First stack question succesfully answered thanks guys!

Comment: @JörgWMittag, almost every library for every language can convert between local time zones and UTC automatically.  In almost all cases (with some exceptions within the scientific community) it's good enough.  The atomic clock (TAI) is not always something you have access to (thinking of private networks here).

Comment: UTC may have leap seconds, but what your OS calls “UTC” may not. Which is fine if you are ok with your clock running slightly faster or slower once a year. Or skipping or inserting a second once a year. And your time may jump if you manually change the clock.

Answer (score 3):

You have basically two choices: If your data is all local, you can record the time in your local time zone without DST, and optionally a flag that DST is used. So when clicks jump forward by an hour, yours doesn’t. If an item is removed from storage 10:30 am today and put back 11:30 tomorrow with DST, the times recorded are exactly 34 hours apart. Your code for displaying data needs adapting.

Better because more future proof is storing the date in UTC or GMT, which both progress by one hour every hour. Optionally record the time zone when the data was recorded, so you know what time was on the user’s watch when he recorded it.

(Note: GMT has no DST. The UK switches to BST in the summer. In GMT each day is exactly 86,400 seconds, but the length of a second varies slightly).

Comment: " UTC or GMT, which both progress by one hour every hour." Minor nit: [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) It doesn't generally matter to most systems but it can create challenges.

Comment: @JimmyJames: Currently all my work is done on a system that claims to use UTC but is blissfully unaware of leap seconds. Or hides them from developers. It may not be the only one. “Seconds since epoch” at an exact hour is always a multiple of 3,600.

Comment: That wikipedia page links to a rabbit hole about [universal time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Time).   While I understand the reason for wanting to adjust the time to account for the earth's rotation, it seems like it would be a lot simpler to have a time that is completely agnostic to that, and then layer UTC on top of it.  Are you aware of such as system?

Comment: @JimmyJames, it's called "TIA", (a French abbreviation for "international atomic time", iirc). Frankly, I can't see any reason whatsoever why UTC adopted leap seconds, or why UTC itself was so widely adopted when it has that feature. TIA is to UTC what the clock is to the sundial!

Comment: @Steve Thanks for that but it seems to be [TAI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Atomic_Time).  It's weird to me that this is so esoteric compared to UTC.  Maybe it's just that it's easier to map from UTC to local time mentally instead of have to subtract 37 seconds (or whatever the current drift is)

Comment: @JimmyJames, agreed! Esoteric enough that I didn't remember the acronym! More sensibly, local time would have been adjusted so as to be a fixed offset from TAI. It's hard to imagine how a 37 second deviation from astronomical phenomena, could have been important to any civil purpose, or that any problem is made simpler by the insertion of ad-hoc leap seconds as in UTC.

Comment: @Steve It just seems archaic to me.  The development of calendars is rooted in agriculture and knowing when to plant.  It as if the momentum of that has led to an obsession with solar time.  I think this hasn't been an issue for a while because seconds have been added.  It when they are subtracted that I think it starts getting interesting.  Mostly that happens after big earthquakes, I think.

Comment: There are two principal time bases: Astronomical day (UT1) and atomic second (TAI). Astronomical day used to be time for the sun to move from one highest position to the next; that is hard to measure precisely because the sun is huge and bright, nowadays it’s based on the time it takes for some quasars to appear in the same position, precise within 15 microseconds. UT1 always has exactly 86,400 seconds in a day. But since the speed of earth rotation changes, these seconds are of variable length. Perfect for the average user.

Comment: TAI is based on the definition of second in physics, produced by averaging the measurements of several nuclear clocks. Length of a second is absolutely fixed. TAI has no leap seconds. At the moment it is 37 seconds ahead of UT1. There are situations where that 37 difference is not acceptable. UTC handled this by adding leap seconds from time to time. 37 since 1970. This is done to keep the difference between UT1 and UTC at less than one seconds.

Comment: @gnasher729: _"“Seconds since epoch” at an exact hour is always a multiple of 3,600"_ As far as humans are concerned, every hour has exactly 3600 seconds. If your application's timestamp are "information for humans" or based on a human schedule (where precise seconds don't matter), rather than a pedantically precise machine schedule for e.g. batch jobs, then it's considerably easier to ignore leap seconds and simply work with the human "leap day" approach.

Comment: Flater, it wouldn’t in UTC. Some hours with 3,601 seconds. Maybe one with 3,599 seconds soon.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons that I store time as UTC.

First, is that with global users of some of the applications I work on, local time varies per user, so local time for a user that entered the data may not be local time for a user viewing the data later.

Second, timezones change. They are subject to the whims of governments. What is UTC +5 today could be UTC +6 tomorrow just because some government says so, which would then make the local time + offset different than what was stored. You can always figure out the correct local time, but I just view it as more work than just converting UTC to local.

Those are the best reasons that I am aware of for using UTC, but I am sure there are others I haven't thought of.

Microsoft document can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.utcnow?view=net-5.0).

Comment: There are conflicting opinions on this, primarily because "figuring out the correct local time" for a past time, can actually be more complicated than one might first suspect, especially if you aren't storing the local time, location, and/or the local timezone alongside the UTC value. And although UTC values improve the comparability of times within the domain of the application, consistency with local civil time can still be more important.

Comment: I’ve seen bugs reported against MacOS when people converted hundred year old dates between utc and local time and got unexpected results. And usually the answer is “conversion is correct, country X used strange local time until 1925”, for example.

Comment: For conversion of historic dates you need not the time zone today, but the time zone when and where the event happened.